# Windows 10 RealVNC Viewer "The connection closed unexpectedly"

Tags: networking, windows-10, vnc, realvnc, vnc-viewer

Suddenly I got this error message when I try to connect to already working connections:

```
The connection closed unexpectedly
```

So, it is not really network issue:

- When I boot in safe mode with networing - it is working normally.
- I have tried to use UltraVNC and TightVNC Viewers -they both work perfectly.
- I can ping the remote PC and connect with ssh.

What can be done, to get the RealVNC Viewer working again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was solved by repairing the windows system with Windows 10 installation media tool.
It was not the firewall or something - just corrupted system files.